# How can I give both images and labels to DataLoader in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 2D tensor which has my frames information and a 1D tensor with the output or label information related to each frame. I make a function and return (frames, labels). Then I give these two to "torch.utils.data.DataLoader()". But the DataLoader is not working for both(frames, labels) and just can iterate for one of them.

Comment: That's odd. Can you please show how your `__getitem__` method of your `Dataset` class returns `frames` and `labels`?

Comment: I used gray images and made 1D arrays of each and append them. so, I have a 2D set of inputs which contains my images. the function returns (frames, labels). and  I give the function output to Dataloader.

Comment: def read_dataset():
    num_train = 2000
    yuv = np.load('H200_Train_dataset.npy')
    label = np.load('Cmpr.npy')

    train_img, train_labels = yuv[:num_train,:], label[:num_train,:]
    test_img, test_labels =yuv[num_train:num_train+200,:], label[num_train:num_train+200,:] 
    return (train_img, train_labels), (test_img, test_labels)

Comment: please do not post code in commets - it cannot be read. Please edit your question and add the code there, *properly formatted*.